A class property is null after second post
I have a simple contact management app.  There are Services and each service has two contacts (DRI and Delegate).  The index page displays the services and their contacts.  The user can check the box on one or many rows and edit the contacts.
The Index page uses JQuery to get the ServiceIds from each checked row.  That is passed to C# in a post and populates the property private List<string>? ServiceIds { get; set; } when the Edit button is clicked.
$(btnEdit).on('click', function () {

    var checkedList = $('[type=checkbox]:checked');
    var ids = []

    for (var item of checkedList) {
        var serviceId = $(item).closest('tr').find(".serviceId").text();
        ids.push(serviceId);
    }  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(ids),
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () {

        }
    });
})

ServiceIds is populated as expected.  Then a modal is opened so the user can enter the Contact info (names and emails). When the modal is submitted the form method calls OnPostSaveAsync to send the contact info to the code-behind
<div id="editDialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Contacts</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Save">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="driName">DRI Name: </label>
                    <input id="driName" type="text" />
                    <label for="driEmail">DRI Email: </label>
                    <input id="driEmail" type="text" />
                    <hr />
                    <label for="delegateName">Delegate Name: </label>
                    <input id="delegateName" type="text" />
                    <label for="delgateEmail">Delegate Email: </label>
                    <input id="delegateEmail" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Here is the post method in Index
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveAsync()
        {
            var dri = Request.Form["driName"].ToString();
            var driEmail = Request.Form["driEmail"].ToString();
            var delegateName = Request.Form["delegateName"].ToString();
            var delegateEmail = Request.Form["delegateEmail"].ToString();

            if (ContactRepository != null && ServiceIds!=null)
            {
                NewContacts = await ContactRepository.GetContactsAsync(ServiceIds).ConfigureAwait(false) ?? new List<Contact> { };
                foreach (var contact in NewContacts!)
                {
                    contact.DRIName = dri ?? string.Empty;
                    contact.DRIEmail = driEmail ?? string.Empty;
                    contact.DelegateName = delegateName ?? string.Empty;
                    contact.DelegateEmail = delegateEmail ?? string.Empty;
                }

                await ContactRepository.UpdateContactsAsync(NewContacts).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return new RedirectToPageResult("Index");
        }


My problem is ServiceIDs is null in this second post action.  The page should not be refreshing so I can't figure out why the property is null.  I'll update the post if you need more context.  I just didn't want to overload it with code.

first, the user can select multiple services, but in your model form, it seems like you are handling only one. Second, in your modal form names should be used in array format like name=driName[ServiceId values][driName]. also, your modal form code missing name attributes for the fields so you will not get data after form submission.

Yes the user can multi-select services but the same form information is applied to all of them.  After form submission I will combine them into a single object to save to the db.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

It always helps to take a step back. I realized I could solve my issue on the JQuery side.  I made checkedList a global parameter so it would live between functions.  I created a new function to handle the user input and pass it back to C#.  I'm going to create an array of the temp objects and send that to C# in a Post.
$(btnSave).on('click', function () {

    var contactList;

    for (var item of checkedList) {
        var serviceId = $(item).closest('tr').find(".serviceId").text();

        var temp = {
            ServiceId: serviceId,
            DRIContact: $('#newDriName').val(),
            DRIEmail: $('#newDriEmail').val(),
            DelegateName: $('#newDelegateName').val(),
            DelegateEmail: $('#newDelegateEmail').val()
        }
    }  

})


